# How is the AND clause used in mysql queries?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have the below code that works fine up to the `AND` clause. The portion of code below that with a `SELECT *`, in front of the `( 3959`, works fine too.  I tried putting the `AND` clause to marry them together but it did not work.

Is it possible with the computation part to combine the `WHERE`, `AND`, and `AS`? I thought `AND` would do the trick but it doesn't. Any ideas?

```php
<?php
    $miles = '25'; //your search radius

    $resul = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT memlocid, LocLat, LocLong
    FROM matmemmatrix 
    inner JOIN matloc
    ON matloc.MLocID = matmemmatrix.memlocid
    WHERE `$a` = '1' AND
    

    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$mylat') ) * 
    cos( radians( LocLat ) ) * 
    cos( radians( LocLong ) - 
    radians('$mylong') ) + 
    sin( radians('$mylat') ) * 
    sin( radians( LocLat ) ) ) ) 
    AS distance FROM matloc HAVING distance < '$miles' ORDER BY 
    distance ASC LIMIT 0, 5");
```

EDITED "Tried" using a subquery (first time)

```php
<?php
$miles = '25'; //your search radius

$resul = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MLocID, LocLat, LocLong, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$mylat') ) * 
cos( radians( LocLat ) ) * 
cos( radians( LocLong ) - 
radians('$mylong') ) + 
sin( radians('$mylat') ) * 
sin( radians( LocLat ) ) ) )
AS distance FROM matloc HAVING distance < '$miles' ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0, 5
WHERE 
    `$a` IN (SELECT 
     memlocid
    FROM
     matmemmatrix
     WHERE `a`='1')");
```

EDITED with no Sub Query

```php
<?php
$miles = '25'; //your search radius

$resul = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MLocID, LocLat, LocLong, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$mylat') ) * 
cos( radians( LocLat ) ) * 
cos( radians( LocLong ) - 
radians('$mylong') ) + 
sin( radians('$mylat') ) * 
sin( radians( LocLat ) ) ) )

AS distance FROM matloc HAVING distance < '$miles' ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0, 5
inner JOIN matmemmatrix
ON matloc.MLocID = matmemmatrix.memlocid
WHERE `$a` = '1'");
```

Both have errors after the "AS" clause.  I tried adding commas and parentheses. And if that is the problem I didn't find the right combo.  I did change the first table to matloc since that is the table where all of the select information is located. matmemmatrix is the table with all the columns I will be checking if "1". There will be a couple hundred columns that I will check if "1".

Here is my error code after I changed it to what might looks to be
working.  The new code I tried is below this new error message.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: This version of MariaDB
 doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' in
 C:\xampp\htdocs\mydb\tempdistance.php:22 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\mydb\tempdistance.php(22):
 mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'SELECT MLocID, ...') #1 {main}
 thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mydb\tempdistance.php on line 22
```

Newest attempt that produced the message above:

```php
<?php
$miles = '25'; //your search radius

$resul = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MLocID, LocLat, LocLong
FROM matloc
inner JOIN matmemmatrix
ON matloc.MLocID = matmemmatrix.memlocid
WHERE `$a` = '1' IN 
    (SELECT ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$mylat') ) * 
cos( radians( LocLat ) ) * 
cos( radians( LocLong ) - 
radians('$mylong') ) + 
sin( radians('$mylat') ) * 
sin( radians( LocLat ) ) ) ) 
AS distance FROM matloc HAVING distance < '$miles' 
ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0, 5)");
```

Comment: The problem is not with the and operator, but that you are trying to use a subquery incorrectly. A subquery starts with select keyword and in the where clause usuall can only return a single value, unless used with in / any / all operators.

Comment: However, I do not think you need a subquery at all. Move the as distance expression into the select list, remove the second from clause, no need for the and operator in the where clause and keep the having and order by clauses of the distance query.

Comment: *I put the 'AND' clause to marry them together and it does not work.* "Does not work" is not a term which can be used. You receive error message which claims that your query is synthactically incorrect.

Comment: I added my 2 edited codes above.  I tried modifying the original by putting the AS clause in the SELECT clause and I also tried to do a subquery for the first time.  Both options still are not working.

Comment: select statements have a specific order the clauses must appear in.  joins belong immediately after from, not after having/order by.  always look at the actual syntax error message, and compare your syntax where it reports a problem to the documentation, and if you need help, show us the full error message.

Comment: NOt an answer to your question, but you may be pleased to read about [ST_Distance_Sphere](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere)

Comment: @Akina Yes actually it is a term that can be used. There was nothing unclear about it. The OP evidently doesn't understand why the code isn't working.